# Почему значение поля id не устанавливается при попытке взять его у только созданного и добавленного в БД объекта

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity

Почему `id = 0` при попытке взять его у только созданного и добавленного в БД объекта.

**Мой код:**

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try (SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class)
                .buildSessionFactory()) {
            Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
            Employee emp = new Employee("Alexandrov", "Vladimir", "IT", 1000);
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(emp);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            session = factory.getCurrentSession();
            int myId = emp.getId();
            System.out.println(myId);
            session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee = session.get(Employee.class, myId);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println(employee.toString());

            System.out.println("Done!");
        }
    }
```

}

**`hibernate.cfg.xml`:**

```xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Настройки подключения к базе данных -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>

        <!-- Другие настройки Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Employee:**

```
package Entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "department")
    private String department;
    @Column(name = "salary")
    private int salary;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String name, String surname, String department, int salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.department = department;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", department='" + department + '\'' +
                ", salary=" + salary +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при попытке вывести `myId`, который равен `emp.getId()`, получается, что `myId = 0`, а объект, соответственно, `null`. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить сеттеры на `Entity`. Без этого Hibernate не сможет установить значение `id`.

Также надо указать что поле `id` имеет нужные аннотации, такие как `@Id`, `@GeneratedValue`, и есть является первичным ключём, и тогда убедившись, что база данных сама создаёт значение этого поля, использовать стратегию `GenerationType.AUTO`.

Примерно так:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!